# How to add a wrapper to the MFC WinMain?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, entry-point, winmain

I want to add a wrapper to the MFC WinMain in order to be able to make a MFC application be able run as GUI application or as a service.

Can I add a wrapper to WinMail from MFC without modifying MFC source code?

Comment: You mean you want to overwrite the MFC-version of WinMain? MFC is a wrapper of this itself.

Comment: For life can't remember, but there was something to let you do it. I remember reading about it in a book named "MFC internals". It was some override, or a bunch of overrides, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, just check the command line parameters in order to change the behavior. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687414(VS.85).aspx

In case you will want to make it work as console remember that it is not possible to make an application that is running as both console and GUI on Windows. Still there is not limitation for services, a service application can be a GUI one or a command line one.